# layout values are not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am developing an android application in that, I am using a layout that contains one main layout called "invitation_single" and two sub layouts are there namely "hidden" and "hidden1", When i am onclick main layout values are gone that works perfectly,after that i am need to visible both sub layout values in that place, i am try below code but sub layout "hidden" values alone display but i am need to display both sub layout values ,how it to be done.Can anyone help me.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:dividerPadding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/invitation_single"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/contact_image"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event" />

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/invitation_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/invitation_place"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:id="@+id/hidden"
            >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yesbutton"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nobutton"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonmaybe"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maybe"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp">
            </Button>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/hidden1"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/place"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

below code is my java code,main layout is"invitation single" ,"hidden" is my first sublayout and "hidden1" is second sublayout,when iam onclick main layout that should be gone and sub layout values are need to be visible,but when i am click main layout sub layout "hidden" alone visible,but i am need to visible both layout.

```
 final LinearLayout first=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);//main layout
               final LinearLayout second = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);//sub layout1
                final LinearLayout third = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden1);//sub layout2
                   first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                      int visibility = second.getVisibility();
                       int visibility1=third.getVisibility();
                           if (visibility == View.GONE)
                           third.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                          }

               });
```

Comment: why are you using converView ? is it a fragment ? post more code

Comment: @selvasimonp Please check my answer in your latest question

Answer (score 0):

First, the formatting of your layout XML is messy!

---

Bad formatting                       *makes* your       **Co

de**
              hard *TO* rea   d,             which makes it di
            **ffic**ult                to find

and**fix**yo    ur*bugs*!!!

---

Formatting your xml cleanly makes it easier to see what is going on, for you and for us.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:dividerPadding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/invitation_single"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/contact_image"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:id="@+id/hidden">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yesbutton"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nobutton"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonmaybe"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Maybe"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"/>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/hidden1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/place"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Breakdown of your layout**

- Your root layout `invitation_single` has no orientation defined, so it will default to being horizontal.
- The horizontal `invitation_single` layout has 4 direct children.
- The 1st direct child `image` is set to a fixed width.
- The widths of the next two `invitation_title` and `invitation_place` are set to `wrap_content`.
- The 4th direct child is a LinearLayout called `hidden`.

  - The orientation of this LinearLayout is also horizontal.
  - The width is set as `match_parent`
  - The layout_weight is set as 1. **This layout will fill the remaining available  width space**
  - The weightSum for this horizontal LinearLayout is set to 3.
  - This horizontal LinearLayout has 4 direct children.
  - The first 3 children are Buttons.

    - Each of the 3 Buttons are assigned a fixed width.
    - Each of the 3 Buttons are also assigned a layout_weight of 1.
    - The weights of the 3 buttons already add up to the weightSum of the LinearLayout they are in.
  - The 4th direct child is  LinearLayout called `hidden1`.

    - The orientation of this LinearLayout is vertical.
    - The width is set as `0dp`
    - The layout_weight is set as 1. **The previous 3 Buttons have already used all the available width space, so `hidden1` will be left with a width of 0dp, which means you will not see it.**

Have a look at the examples in this blog [Android, LinearLayout Distribution Explained (weight and sizes)](http://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/) to get a better understanding of how layout_weight works.